Private Custom Smartsheet Addon
Hullo!
I am a contract developer for a company that uses Smartsheet. They would like me to develop a private addon for their use. Is this possible? If so, could you point me to the documentation?
I searched the API documentation, but was unable to find the answer I seek.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
